# Find a pattern in a stream of bytes read in blocks

Tags: python, performance, search, stream, block

I have a stream of gigabytes of data that I read in blocks of 1 MB.

I'd like to find if (and where) one of the patterns `PATTERNS = [b"foo", b"bar", ...]` is present in the data (case insensitive).

Here is what I'm doing. It works but it is sub-optimal:

```
oldblock = b''
while True:
    block = source_data.get_bytes(1024*1024)
    if block == b'':
        break
    testblock = (oldblock + block).lower()
    for PATTERN in PATTERNS:
        if PATTERN in testblock:
            for l in testblock.split(b'\n'):  # display only the line where the 
                if PATTERN in l:              # pattern is found, not the whole 1MB block!
                    print(l)                  # note: this line can be incomplete if 
    oldblock = block                          # it continues in the next block (**)
```

Why do we need to search in `oldblock + block`? This is because the pattern `foo` could be *precisely* split in two consecutive 1 MB blocks:

```
[.......fo] [o........]
block n     block n+1
```

Drawback: it's not optimal to have to concatenate `oldblock + block` and to perform the search almost twice as much as necessary.

We *could* use `testblock = oldblock[-max_len_of_patterns:] + block`, but there is surely a more canonical way to address this problem, as well as the side-remark (**).

**How to do a more efficient pattern search in data read by blocks?**

Note: the input data is not a file that I can iterate on or memory map, I only receive a stream of 1MB blocks from an external source.

Comment: How long are your patterns, how many patterns do you have, how long are your lines?

Comment: @KellyBundy Typically: pattern_length < 100 char, number_of_patterns < 1000, line_length < 1 KB.

Comment: You might print the same line many times, even twice for the same pattern. Is that ok?

Comment: @KellyBundy If a line contains "foo bar foo", and one pattern is "foo", then the line might be printed twice, that's ok.

Comment: What I meant was that you'll likely print that line twice for pattern "bar" as well, so [four times](https://tio.run/##ZZHBboMwDIbvPIUHh4CGKk27TEg9dNKOm6att60HUoyImiVZSMV4euYEaIvIJbF/@/ttxfSu0erxydhheN/t9y8fb5@whS8e11rHOfCYlzY@RBGX@nhqvRQBHc5IB9KA7m/F8in7e/5j0SHSsgoNVM8Zi2ptYYyFGh9tERpEPeW3oXBMBpLF8hQih62bWemFez/2ZRupO7RpFkq9zbSEN5r3uVLJ7ka/kK8FM0Uu9E1rpHApZ7RoVgAkUAlKlT1oJXtwDYIUCqFr0GIIF8C1syyWagKmdA6tAtGS/1lVOSjtAqprtER4eH0eN75bof0xViiXymytJB6EBaEIHaY8lvQHSGMc9Y@R6NAPF6i3v@bvYfgH)  overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd separate the block-getting from the pattern-searching and do it like this (all but the first two lines are from your original):

```
for block in nice_blocks():
    testblock = block.lower()
    for PATTERN in PATTERNS:
        if PATTERN in testblock:
            for l in testblock.split(b'\n'):  # display only the line where the 
                if PATTERN in l:              # pattern is found, not the whole 1MB block!
                    print(l)
```

Where `nice_blocks()` is an iterator of "nice" blocks, meaning they don't break lines apart and they don't overlap. And they're ~1 MB large as well.

To support that, I start with a helper just providing an iterator of the raw blocks:

```
def raw_blocks():
    while block := source_data.get_bytes(1024*1024):
        yield block
```

(The `:=` assumes you're not years behind, it was added in Python 3.8. For older versions, do it with your `while-True-if-break`).

And to get *nice* blocks:

```
def nice_blocks():
    carry = b''
    for block in raw_blocks():
        i = block.rfind(b'\n')
        if i >= 0:
            yield carry + block[:i]
            carry = block[i+1:]
        else:
            carry += block
    if carry:
        yield carry
```

The `carry` carries over remaining bytes from the previous block (or previous blocks, if none of them had newlines, but that's not happening with your "blocks of 1 MB" and your "line_length < 1 KB").

With these two helper functions in place, you can write your code as at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the use of `testblock.split(b'\n')` in your code, as well as the comment about displaying the line where a pattern is found, it is well apparent that your expected input is not a true binary file, but a text file, where each line, separated by `b'\n'`, is of a size reasonable enough to be readable by the end user when displayed on a screen. It is therefore most convenient and efficient to simply iterate through the file by lines instead of in chunks of a fixed size since the iterator of a file-like object already handles buffering and splitting by lines optimally.

However, since it is now clear from your comment that `data` is not really a file-like object in your real-world scenario, but an API that presumably has just a method that returns a chunk of data per call, we have to wrap that API into a file-like object.

For demonstration purpose, let's simulate the API you're dealing with by creating an API class that returns up to 10 bytes of data at a time with the `get_next_chunk` method:

```
class API:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.position = 0

    def get_next_chunk(self):
        chunk = self.data[self.position:self.position + 10]
        self.position += 10
        return chunk
```

We can then create a subclass of `io.RawIOBase` that wraps the API into a file-like object with a `readinto` method that is necessary for a file iterator to work:

```
import io

class APIFileWrapper(io.RawIOBase):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        self.leftover = None

    def readable(self):
        return True

    def readinto(self, buffer):
        chunk = self.leftover or api.get_next_chunk()
        size = len(buffer)
        output = chunk[:size]
        self.leftover = chunk[size:]
        output_size = len(output)
        buffer[:output_size] = output
        return output_size
```

With a raw file-like object, we can then wrap it in an `io.BufferedReader` with a buffer size that matches the size of data returned by your API call, and iterate through the file object by lines and use the built-in `in` operator to test if a line contains one of the patterns in the list:

```
api = API(b'foo bar\nHola World\npython\nstackoverflow\n')
PATTERNS = [b't', b'ho']

for line in io.BufferedReader(APIFileWrapper(api), 10): # or 1024 * 1024 in your case
    lowered_line = line.lower()
    for pattern in PATTERNS:
        if pattern in lowered_line:
            print(line)
            break
```

This outputs:

```
b'Hola World\n'
b'python\n'
b'stackoverflow\n'
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/CelebratedCadetblueWifi

Comment: Searching chunks can be [slightly faster](https://tio.run/##TY/BasMwDIbvegrdlBQzlmYdo9AnWXtoWoeaxZZRlEOfPrWcDeaDQf//@TPKT31w6r@yrOsoHFFD9EExxMyivxPA7HXJeEIhIhgmvv2UgUbmcyLc4f7wWe7uff8BU0h@LmWF3uY8Ba1R00K@qnpJ9nK4CoG5bnyv@DdgOfSHhLQJyG35yIKmsaLqjvgPtaSQFwDjTGnppt5hf6wOLb9s6zTWOKw7OUxLHLycurZSWULSRnhJ90ZtJ9877FqHFGckV6Xtur4A) (but depends on how often the patterns appear).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do any benchmarks but this solution has the definite advantage of being straight forward and not looking everywhere twice, print the lines as they actually appear in the stream (and not in all lower case) and print the complete lines even if they cross a block:

```
import re

regex_patterns = list(re.compile('^.*'+re.escape(pattern)+'.*$',re.I|re.M) for pattern in PATTERNS)

testblock = ""
block = data.read(1024*1024) # **see remark below**
while len(block)>0:
    lastLineStart = testblock.rfind('\n')+1
    testblock = testblock[lastLineStart:]+block.decode('UFT-8') # **see edit below**
    for pattern in regex_patterns:
        for line in pattern.findall(testblock):
            print(line)
    block = data.read(1024*1024) # **see remark below**
```

Remark: Since you are processing text data here (otherwise the notion of "lines" wouldn't make any sense), you shouldn't be using `b'...'` anywhere. Your text in the stream has some encoding and you should read it in a way that honours that encoding (instead of data.read(1024*1024)) so that the loops are operating on real (Python internal unicode) strings and not some byte data. Not getting that straight is one of the most frustratingly difficult bugs to find in each and every Python script.

Edit: If your data is coming from someplace you don't have control over, then using block.decode('UTF-8') (where 'UTF-8' should be replaced by your data's actual encoding!) would allow for the patterns to be Python unicode strings as well. Meaning you could drop the b'..' around those as well. Naturally... if your data is all strictly 7-bit anyway, those points are mute.

Comment: You make a good point about processing encoded text as a binary file. See my answer in which I explain that if the text file contains non-ascii characters (obviously encoded), then you may match “characters” that are not really on character boundaries. However, for ascii text files using mmap allows you to treat the entire file as a single string and search it very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
Only concat the end of the first block and start of the next block using the length of the pattern that you are currently looking for. Then use a variable (carry) to indicate if you found the pattern or not so that when you move to the next block you automatically print the first line because you already know that line started with the pattern.

E.g.

block_0 = "abcd"
block_1 = "efgh"

pattern = "def"
length = 3

if pattern in block_0[-length + 1:] + block_1[:length - 1]

This if statement will check "cdef" for the pattern "def". No need to check any more characters than that because if it isn't in that selection of characters then it isn't between blocks in the first place. Now you know the pattern is across blocks, you just need to print the first line of the next block which will be done by checking the value of carry as seen below.

This should stop you needing to go through the block twice like you said.

```
oldblock = b''
carry = False
while True:
    block = data.read(1024*1024)
    if block == b'':
        break
    block = block.lower()
    lines =  block.split(b'\n')
    if carry:
        print(lines[0])             
        carry = False
    for PATTERN in PATTERNS:
        if PATTERN in block:
            for l in lines:
                if PATTERN in l:              
                    print(l)
        length = len(PATTERN)
        if PATTERN in (block[-length + 1:] + oldblock[:length - 1]):
            carry = True     #Found the PATTERN between blocks, indicate that the first line of the next block needs to be printed      
    oldblock = block
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Given what we now know about the nature of the data, then we only need to retain from a previous call to `get_bytes` the last N characters where N is the maximum pattern length - 1. And since a portion of the previous block retrieved must be concatenated with the newly read block in order to match patterns that are split across block boundaries, it then becomes possible to match the same pattern twice. Therefore, it only makes sense that once a pattern has been matched we do not try to match it again. And, of course, when there are no more patterns to match we can quit.

The pattern strings, if not Ascii, should be encoded with the same encoding being used in the stream.

```py
PATTERNS = [b'foo', b'bar', 'coûteux'.encode('utf-8')]
BLOCKSIZE = 1024 * 1024

FILE_PATH = 'test.txt'

# Compute maximum pattern length - 1
pad_length = max(map(lambda pattern: len(pattern), PATTERNS)) - 1

with open(FILE_PATH, 'rb') as f:
    patterns = PATTERNS
    # Initialize with any byte string we are not trying to match.
    data = b'\x00' * pad_length
    offset = 0
    # Any unmatched patterns left?:
    while patterns:
        # Emulate a call to get_bytes(BLOCKSIZE) using a binary file:
        block = f.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        if block == b'':
            break
        # You only need to keep the last pad_length bytes from previous read:
        data = data[-pad_length:] + block.lower()
        # Once a pattern is matched we do not want to try matching it again:
        new_patterns = []
        for pattern in patterns:
            idx = data.find(pattern)
            if idx != -1:
                print('Found: ', pattern, 'at offset', offset + idx - pad_length)
            else:
                new_patterns.append(pattern)
        offset += BLOCKSIZE
        patterns = new_patterns
```

Comment: By evaluating `mm[:].lower()` you load the entire gigabytes of data in memory. Not the memory-saving behavior that the OP wants by streaming the input in blocks of 1MB.

Comment: Thanks but my input data is not a file, I cannot memory map it, I receive blocks of 1 MB from an external source, and I cannot memory map it or iterate on it.

Comment: @Basj Please update your question with code that better represents the kind of API you're dealing with, instead of making it looks as if `data` is a file-like object that supports regular file methods. Without knowing what the API you're dealing with does or does not support, it's hard to give an optimal answer that helps your actual situation.

Comment: The point made by @blhsing is well taken, however, I don't believe that Method 4 using regular expressions suffers the same problem.  However, this is all moot based on your saying that data in essence  must be read in blocks. We still have the issue of reading data as bytes that contains text. If this is encoded text, i.e. text containing anything other than Ascii characters, even if the "strings" you are trying to match are all Ascii, you may end up falsely matching bytes that are not on an encoded character boundary as I have indicated in my answer. So what is the nature of this data?

Comment: If both text and pattern are in UTF-8, I don't see how the pattern could match anywhere other than properly on a boundary. Would like to see an example.

Comment: @KellyBundy I now believe you are correct. And if the data is encoded with utf-8, then you must do the matching using the raw bytes (i.e. without decoding the data) because if you read in a fixed length block and attempt to decode it  first so you can do regular string matching you could get a decoding error because the block ends in the middle of a multibyte encoded character.

Answer (score -3):

1. if patern matched, try to use "break;" word inside "for" body for breaking execution of already useless code
2. and use {...} for start and finish "for" loop body like:

for (...)
{ if match(PATTERN) break;
}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About 1. even if the pattern is found, I still want to find if the pattern is present somewhere else in the rest of the file, this is way I don't `break`. About 2. we don't use `{ ... }` in Python ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).